# Modify data of an intent filter programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, dropbox-api

If you want to use Dropbox from an app, you have to register at Dropbox and you will get an app-key and an app-secret. Because it is very insecure to code the password and the key in the app from my own dropbox account, each user should register himself at Dropbox. In the app they have to input the key and secret in an the Dropbox options.

Now my question. How can I replace programmaticaly the data of the intent-filter with the real value from the options? Or is it another way to handle this?

I have the following intent-filter in my manifest file:

> ```
>   <activity
>     android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
>     android:launchMode="singleTask"
>     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
>     <intent-filter>
>       <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
>       <data android:scheme="db-xxxxxxxx" />
>       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
>       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>     </intent-filter>
>   </activity>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because it is very insecure to code the password and the key in the app from my own dropbox account, each user should register himself at Dropbox.

Unless Dropbox really screwed up, the API key is for developers, not users.

> How can I replace programmaticaly the data of the intent-filter with the real value from the options?

You can't.

> Or is it another way to handle this?

Register for an API key, and put the API key where Dropbox tells you to put the API key.

Or, do not use their API, but instead try to interoperate with their Android app (e.g., `ACTION_SEND`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: The problem is not only the APP key but the corresponding APP secret which I have to use in the app to authorize. How if I obfuscate the code? Is that secure?

Comment: @egmontr: "How if I obfuscate the code? Is that secure?" -- your key and secret are not code, but data. That will not be obfuscated by tools like ProGuard. DexGuard will, and there may be other products for this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t mention that the secret is used only in the code and the key in code and manifest.
    
    `
    final static private String APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    final static private String APP_SECRET = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";`

Comment: @egmontr: As I wrote in my previous comment, those strings will not be obfuscated by tools like ProGuard. DexGuard will, and there may be other products for this. ProGuard obfuscates your programming symbols, such as class and method names, not data like strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to interoperate with Dropbox app or obfuscate with DexGuard or similar products.